# I am getting parse_str() error while implementing facebook login with laravel socialite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am implementing facebook login with socialite laravel but after successful login with facebook when it return me back to callback url i receive an error

1. laravel version 5.6
2. Socailite version 3.0
3. php version 7.2

```php
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}

/**
 * Obtain the user information from facebook.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

    return $user->token;
}
```

Erros look like this.

> parse_str(): Calling parse_str() without the result argument is deprecated
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\laravel\socialite\src\Two\FacebookProvider.php

Routes.php

```
// FACEBOOK ROUTES
Route::get('login/facebook', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('login/facebook/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
// FACEBOOK ROUTES END HERE
```

Comment: What is the exact version of Socialite that you're using i.e. `3.0.*`?

Comment: my composer.json file  "laravel/socialite": "3.0",

Answer (score 1):

`parse_str()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

> Using this function without the result parameter is highly DISCOURAGED and DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.

---

Looking at the version history for the `FacebookProvider` class on Github the error only seems to exist in version 3.0.0, however, there is not mention of `parse_str` at all in `3.0.4`.

To fix your issue you can run:

```
composer require laravel/socialite:^3.0.4
```